# Web-Service returns an object I can't work with JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm creating a client of a web service - " www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx " that returns all the cities and there post codes from that state(I'll be using that information for an weather broadcast program).

`ipSoap.getInfoByState()` returns an object GetInfoByStateResult(gibs fron now on). Now the problem is that i can't access the content gibs has. The getContent() method returns a List of objects yet it has no methods that allow me to get the data I want (the Names and the Zips).

How do I get the Name of the Cities and the Zips from the response ?

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        USZip ip = new USZip();
        USZipSoap ipSoap = ip.getUSZipSoap();
        GetInfoByStateResult gibs = ipSoap.getInfoByState("NJ"); //New York
        List<Object> listOfCities = gibs.getContent();
               /* problem here, getContent is always size 1, and i can't see what's inside in it. gibs.getIndex(0).toString returns: [NewDataSet: null].
*/

        }
}
```

GetCityByResult is at the bottom

```
/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="GetInfoByCityResult" minOccurs="0">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;any/>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getInfoByCityResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetInfoByCityResponse")
public class GetInfoByCityResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "GetInfoByCityResult")
    protected GetInfoByCityResponse.GetInfoByCityResult getInfoByCityResult;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the getInfoByCityResult property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link GetInfoByCityResponse.GetInfoByCityResult }
     *     
     */
    public GetInfoByCityResponse.GetInfoByCityResult getGetInfoByCityResult() {
        return getInfoByCityResult;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the getInfoByCityResult property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link GetInfoByCityResponse.GetInfoByCityResult }
     *     
     */
    public void setGetInfoByCityResult(GetInfoByCityResponse.GetInfoByCityResult value) {
        this.getInfoByCityResult = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;any/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "content"
    })
    public static class GetInfoByCityResult {

        @XmlMixed
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        protected List<Object> content;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the content property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getContent().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link String }
         * {@link Object }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<Object> getContent() {
            if (content == null) {
                content = new ArrayList<Object>();
            }
            return this.content;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The web-service appears to be returning very general XML, as indicated by the `any` element in the schema.

According to the [JAXB documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_of__xs_any___.html):

> JAXB binds any such element to an Object, and during unmarshalling,
>   all elements encountered are unmarshalled into corresponding JAXB
>   objects (including JAXBElements if necessary) and placed in this
>   field. If it encounters elements that cannot be unmarshalled, DOM
>   elements are produced instead.

This means that if `GetInfoByCityResult` contains elements that conform to a schema that you have generated Java classes for, instances of those classes will be returned; otherwise the raw DOM elements will be returned.

IMHO, it's a bit slack for the service provider to use such a general schema - in order to consume the XML, in anything more than generic display of its elements, you need to be able to attach meaning to those elements, which if they're not defined in a schema is impossible.

In your case this means you'll need to debug your code and look at the elements being returned by the web-service, then code to those elements (hoping they don't change).